# Recursive serial call promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I want to implement a recursive serial call to the promise method `times`, returning the result of the `fn` function of calling N times to the array.

At present, I added an additional attribute `results` to the `times` function to save the results of each `fn` call.

I also don’t want to use module-scoped variables to save the results. Or, save the results by passing additional parameters like `times(fn, n, results)`, it will break the function signature.

`async/await` syntax is not allowed.

Is there any way to only use function local variables to save the result?

```
const times = Object.assign(
  (fn: (...args: any) => Promise<any>, n: number = 1) => {
    if (n === 0) return times.results;
    return fn().then((res) => {
      times.results.push(res);
      return times(fn, --n);
    });
  },
  { results: [] as any[] },
);
```

Usage:

```js
const createPromise = (args: any) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`[${new Date().toISOString()}]args: `, args);
      resolve(args);
    }, 1000);
  });

async function test() {
  const actual = await times(() => asyncFn('data'), 3);
  console.log(actual);  // output: [ 'data', 'data', 'data' ]
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use `async/ await`?

Comment: @Rajesh Updated question. It's not allowed.

Comment: You are trying to do something promise were meant to resolve... Sequential and callback hell... That said, async/ await is the easiest option. Thinking for recursion but a bit complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to use a stateful `result` variable at all. Just invert the recursion direction:

```
function times<T>(fn: () => Promise<T>, n: number = 1): Promise<T[]> {
  if (n === 0) return Promise.resolve([]);
  else return times(fn, n-1).then(results =>
    fn().then(res => {
      results.push(res);
      return results;
    })
  });
}
```

But if you insist on creating promises more gradually, you'll need to use an accumulator parameter:

```
function times<T>(fn: () => Promise<T>, n: number = 1, results: T[] = []): Promise<T[]> {
  if (n === 0) return Promise.resolve(results);
  else return fn().then(res => {
    results.push(res);
    return times(fn, n-1, results);
  });
}
```

If you don't like having that additional optional parameter in your signature, use a local helper function that does the recursion:

```
function times<T>(fn: () => Promise<T>, n: number = 1): Promise<T[]> {
  function recurse(n: number, results: T[]): Promise<T[]> {
    if (n === 0) return Promise.resolve(results);
    else return fn().then(res => {
      results.push(res);
      return recurse(n-1, results);
    });
  }
  return recurse(n, []);
}
// or more ugly (stateful):
function times<T>(fn: () => Promise<T>, n: number = 1): Promise<T[]> {
  let results: T[] = [];
  function recurse(): Promise<T[]> {
    if (n-- === 0) return Promise.resolve(results);
    else return fn().then(res => {
      results.push(res);
      return recurse();
    });
  }
  return recurse();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to achieve is to have a sequential and a recursive pattern. You can achieve it as following

#### [Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/w2mj9kL4/1/):

- In your function create 2 promises

  - `finalPromise`: Promise to be returned from function
  - `promise`: Promise that will be created by passed `fn`
- For `finalPromise`, copy reference of resolver function and store it for manual call, say `resolverFn`
- Create a variable `result` to store values. This should be of type `any[]`
- On `promise.then`,

  - Push received value in `result`
  - Make subsequent call to times.
- Trick for subsequent calls,

  - Callback passed to `times` will be `resolverFn` if `n === 1`. Make sure to bind `result` before you pass or do `() => resolverFn(result)`
  - Else pass `fn`
- Store output of this call, say `innerPromise` and on it's then, call `resolverFn` with `result`

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!